# Allow certain user role to add tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have added a taxonomy entity reference on a node. I want users of certain roles to only select from the list and not allow them to create a new one.

A user role A to select from the list or add a new one.

I have checked the box in the reference field setting 'Create referenced entities if they don't already exist' and only administrator and user role A has permission to create/edit term. But still the form allows other users to add new term, how can I stop this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want specific roles to access denied on taxonomy term create/edit then you can set permission on taxonomy term.
2. If you want specific roles to access denied on node taxonomy field then you can use this module :"https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions" and set permission.